# Using Swift to SSH

Tags: ios, swift

Does anyone know a way to use swift to SSH into a server and retrieve information to then display in an iOS app? I've tried using NMSSH but keep running into declaration errors. I have already set up the NMSSH framework and created a bridging header file to connect NMSHH to my project but now I'm unsure how to use NMSSH since it is written in objective-c and the file I'm trying to implement it in is a .swift file. I have been told that you can use objective-c classes in .swift files but I'm unsure how to implement NMSSH into a objective-c class in which then I can use in my .swift file. Below is my code in my objective-c class so far.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <NMSSH/NMSSH.h>

@interface SSH : NSObject


NMSSHSession *session = [NMSSHSession connectToHost:@"127.0.0.1:22" withUsername:@"user"];

if (session.isConnected) {
[session authenticateByPassword:@"pass"];

if (session.isAuthorized) {
    NSLog("Authentication succeeded");
}
}

NSError *error = nil;
NSString *response = [session.channel execute:@"ls -l /var/www/" error:&error];
NSLog(@"List of my sites: %@", response);

BOOL success = [session.channel uploadFile:@"~/index.html" to:@"/var/www/9muses.se/"];

[session disconnect];
@end
```

Comment: NMSSH should work with Swift. Can you post the code you've tried and what errors you're getting? How are you bringing in the NMSSH framework?

Comment: I figured out that I was trying to use the NMSSH objective-c syntax in a swift file but now I'm confused about how to actually implement NMSSH into that swift file I'm writing my code in.

Comment: It would help if you showed what you've tried. See [Ask]

Comment: Do not post screenshots, paste your code.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Objective-C code in a Swift file, that's why it's not working.

Comment: (You were before you edited your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42120298/revisions)